# Pass list of string into Controller in mvc 3 Razor

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have the problems with pass list of string into controller in mvc 3 Razor
I use Jquery to set value.
But in the server side the first value always false, I don't know why :(
Here my code:
Class:

```
public class ListFieldInfo
{
    public List<string> FieldFilters { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Export", "Books", FormMethod.Post,new { @id = "exportForm", hidden = true }))
    {
    <fieldset>
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.status_info.FieldFilters, new { @id = "status_filters" })
    </fieldset>      
    }
```

Javascript:

```
$('#status_filters').add("0");
$('#status_filters').add("1");
```

Debug in controller:

```
FieldFilters[0] = "false"// I don't know why
FieldFilters[1] = "1"
```

I tried to search google and stackoverflow but still no help
Please help me, thank in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case you need to receive single string for one HiddenField and split it on the server side.

If you need to receive List you need to build set of controls with names like:

```
<input type="hidden" name="model.status_info.FieldFilters" />
<input type="hidden" name="model.status_info.FieldFilters" />
etc...
```

Here is great article from Phill Haak: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In a javascript console, try the following:

```
"0" == false
```

Helpful, eh? I suspect MVC Is playing silly beggars, assuming that's what you meant. First, try inspecting the POST request in the net panel of Firebug (or whatever web debugging you use), then I'd suggest you try using plain numbers instead of strings.